# Two texts aligned. One over an Image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML ([JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1bvmj5xL/3/)):

```
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Header Text</p>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="intro">

  <div class="frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x240">
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Body text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Objectives**

1. Body Text must be over the Image;
2. Body Text and Header Text must be left aligned.

The problem is when resizing the screen to a small size Body Text and Header Text are not aligned.

Wrapper class is responsible to keep a center aligned region, with width up to 1024px, where content is placed like "header text" and "body text" ...

How to solve this?

The CSS code is the following:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 
  .wrapper { padding: 0 40px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) {  
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
      width: 90%;
  }
}

img {
  height: auto;  
  max-width: 100%;
  outline: 0; 
  width: 100%;
}

div.intro {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 

  div.frame {
    margin: 0 -14rem; 
  }

  div.frame {
    margin: 0 -4rem; 
  }

}

div.inner {
  max-width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Actually when JSFiddle is fullsized, they are not aligned, but the header is a bit more to the right than the body text. They both are aligned in the same direction when the window is smaller. In both cases they are aligned left though

Comment: set `width: 100%;`  instead of `90%` in `.wrapper`

Comment: @MonarthSarvaiya I can't change wrapper that way ... Wrapper defines a center region of the page where Content must be ... So I need the Body text to be on that center region but over the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this css code

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 @media screen  { 
   .wrapper { padding: 0 40px;}
 }

 @media screen {  
   .wrapper {
      width: 90%;
   }
 }

 img {
   height: auto;  
   max-width: 100%;
   outline: 0; 
   width: 100%;
 }

 div.intro {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;  
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 

   div.frame {
     margin: 0 -14rem; 
   }

   div.frame {
     margin: 0 -4rem; 
   }

 }

 div.inner {
   max-width: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
 }
```

Comment: I can't use your code because now the wrapper is not center aligned: https://jsfiddle.net/78gjvde5/ ... Please, compare with mine: https://jsfiddle.net/1bvmj5xL/3/ ... Basically wrapper defines a region center aligned where content is.

Comment: I do not understand the code you just suggested in jsfiddle.net/kv13Lxjr/2. The Header and Body Text sections (red outline) are not centered in page

Comment: No ... :-( ... Please check the link https://jsfiddle.net/1bvmj5xL/3/. It is the red rectangle that should be centered in the page ... Not the text inside it ... In the Header is correct. But in the body text not ...

Comment: No it is not ... Please, check the code in https://jsfiddle.net/1bvmj5xL/3/ and resize the window ... Check that the Header rectangle with red outline is always centered on page when resized.